# Is there a way to change a True False to Yes No in PowerBI Slicer visual

Tags: powerbi

Currently the table is is a True False. For some reason, management wants to see a Yes/ No instead of T/F on the Dashboard report. I like to just change the naming convention in the visual alone, but the table still reflecting True/ False. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can quickly create a table in PowerQuery with the following values :

| Value | Desc |
| --- | --- |
| True | Yes |
| False | No |

Note, don't forget to specify the type :

- `Value` → True/False
- `Desc` → Text

Then, you create a relationship between the True/False value from your model to the `Value` column from this newly created table.

And, you use the `Desc` column in your slicer.